# self.prop=nil; vs. [prop release];prop=nil;

Tags: objective-c

If I am using synthesized properties, then why wouldn't I simply say :

```
self.property = nil;
```

This will release the ref count, and make sure I don't have a dangling pointer.

Seems straightforward, and yet 99% of code I see seems to do it this way:

```
[property release];
property = nil;
```

and yes, in most cases they are properties. 
I get the horrible feeling I am missing something?
Sorta like when I forgot to put "self." in front of some of the properties and wondered why it was crashing :-)

Answer (score 9):

If you're trying to clear the value of a property anywhere but in a dealloc method, then `self.property = nil;` is the best way to do it. It'll handle all the memory management tasks for you, helping to prevent any issues.

If you are in the `dealloc` method, than the best way to release that ivar is up for debate, but `[property release];` tends to be recommended, since calling `self.property` may have secondary effects. In the `dealloc` method, calling `property = nil;` is not necessary.

Comment: With one caveat;  `self.property = nil;` will fire any KV observers whereas direct access will not.   Either way works, but which one is appropriate is a matter of opinion.

Comment: It also depends what the desired outcome is. Sometimes you want those observers to fire, sometimes you want to bypass them.