# Difference between [foo release] and self.foo = nil;

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [self.prop=nil; vs. [prop release];prop=nil;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702609/self-prop-nil-vs-prop-releaseprop-nil)

Can anyone help, What is the difference between `[foo release]` and `self.foo = nil;`?

Comment: This has been covered a million times. It has to do with how the properties (keyword) are synthesized, if at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702609/self-prop-nil-vs-prop-releaseprop-nil , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212628/whats-the-difference-between-setting-an-object-to-nil-vs-sending-it-a-release , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091394/is-setting-a-property-to-nil-same-as-releasing-the-property

Comment: The former releases the object address by foo.  The latter does than and also sets the pointer to foo to nil.  I've come to prefer the latter, even in dealoc routines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is some nice tutorial and explanation about it. It's simple, really.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2712/using-properties-in-objective-c-tutorial